# How to avoid of missing cell's border when a record is separated between 2 pages?

Tags: jasper-reports, report, ireport

When the last entry in a page is too long, It will show in next page, when it show all the table line is missing.

This is the result:

[image]

How do I move the last record (no.26) to the next page, or how I can show the line?

Answer (score 6):

You can put the `staticText` element without text behind the `textField` element. You should set ***`stretchType`*** property with **RelativeToTallestObject** value and ***`isPrintWhenDetailOverflows`*** property with **true** value.

The sample:

```xml
<detail>
    <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
            <box>
                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement/>
            <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
            <box>
                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
```

As result you will get the vertical border at the second page.

[image: The text from resulting PDF file with vertical border after using the staticText]

The result **before** adding the second `staticText` was (*the vertical border at the second page is absent*):

[image: The text from resulting PDF file without vertical border before using the staticText]

Comment: i have try the way is success but there are repeating lines for every row. How avoid that?. this is my pictures http://i.stack.imgur.com/mFIKl.jpg

Answer (score 4):

Better way is to ensure, that new items in Detail band (or any band) will be generated on next page by setting, but not on the text field. For the band the text field is in, you can set the Split Type to Prevent. if you set that on the Detail Band and the row needs to overflow to next page, it will move the entire row to the next page.