# JasperReports: Subreport properties "Print In First Whole Band"

Tags: jasper-reports, border, stretch, subreport

First sorry for my English - it's not native for me.
I've create report with subreport. Subreport print some records, each *textField* is surrounded by border (It should look like a table). And when some *textField*'s Height is too large - it breaks and continue to print text on next page - and thats Ok, but the other *textField* elements in a row are left on previous page - and their borders don't show on new page. This cause the report to look with only alone *textField* in a row (first row on new page). See attach: Red line - text is carry over to new page. Green markers - text fields left at prev page.

[image]

I've tried to use ***Print In First Whole Band*** property to avoid row breaking, but Subreport don't react on it. Probably this is JasperReports issue.

Please advice how can I make my report looks fine, without empty spaces instead of borders when starting new page ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870482/how-to-combining-a-record-that-separate-between-2-pages-in-ireport. You can read my answer on this question

Comment: Great, thanks! The result is exactly what I need !  This is some kind of workover. So the "Print In First Whole Band" doesn't work as should ?

Comment: Welcome :) `So the "Print In First Whole Band" doesn't work as should?` - I think you're wrong in understanding this property. You can read the [JasperReports Ultimate Guide](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/JasperReports-Ultimate-Guide-3.pdf) for better understanding

Comment: Ok. I understand. This flag work in combination with "Print Repeated Values".    So, here is a new question: Is there any possibility to don't allow detail band (and all field on it) to break ? And, if there is a possibility of breaking any object on it, then band should start new page.

Comment: You can read [this post](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=102&forumid=103&topicid=4390) and [this post](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=83&forumid=101&topicid=48255) on http://jasperforge.org

Comment: Thank you very much! I think i've got enough information on my questions. Should I close my Question somehow ?

Comment: Welcome :) Hmmm, I don't know what should you do. Your original question duplicates another question, may be you should delete the question. You can look for the rule on meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: But on the other side, IMHO, your question contains more information and more clear that the original.