# How to keep the line row for repeating values in iReport 2.0.2?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

In my table I have repeating value.

I have put ***`isPrintRepeatedValues=false`*** to avoid the repeat values. It was success but I found that the left border is missing for the left cell in a row.

How to make to cover his line for a repeat row only?

The result would be as at the picture (highlighting area) below:

[image]

Comment: `It was success but I found that his line does not cover all the row` - Can you illustrate your post with screenshot?

Comment: how to post the images?.I tried to find the button images but no have

Comment: See [How to upload an image to a post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: This is my example images.http://i.stack.imgur.com/992M5.jpg. i want the result as i highlight in below of pictures.

Comment: You can look at my answer on [How to avoid of missing cell's border when a record is separated between 2 pages?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8872460/876298) question. You have the same case

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid of missing cell's border when a record is separated between 2 pages?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8870482/876298)

Comment: i have try you way but still this is not what i want. What i want is the lines is not repeating eventhough the data is repeat. How to do that?.