# the vertical border not continue

Tags: jasper-reports

I send a datasource from my java application to jasper report. everything was fine until I decided to merge the same value in the last column together. I unchecked the "print repeated values" in the properties of text field.
now my question is that why the most right vertical border not continue?

here is xml configuration of text file

```
<jr:column width="70" uuid="41ac4ca7-80a0-4eb6-8b97-bdd43ecd25e5">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column7"/>
                    <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="70" height="30" uuid="5a20f1b8-1236-4601-94bc-1d14e16ad6eb"/>
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                            </box>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="B Titr" size="16" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[فروشگاه]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:tableHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="40">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement style="Zebra" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="70" height="40" uuid="263dd7d8-1f91-40e6-828c-85aef48f4c37"/>
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="0.1" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="B Yekan"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{shopName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
```

and here is sample output

[image]

Comment: You can check [How to avoid of missing cell's border when a record is separated between 2 pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8870482/876298) post

Comment: @AlexK but my report just produces 1 page, And the above image is its output